# SyntaxError reported in facebook's all.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

As of this morning (it was ok yesterday afternoon), I'm seeing "Unexpected token ," twice in http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

Comment: And? Maybe you should send it to FB devs not here?

Comment: I did.  There's a stackoverflow site that's supposed to be just for Facebook now (it's new). In the requirements, I even was forced to include Facebook-specific tags.  (facebook.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Hmmm... good to know. Still, IMO it's strange to use SO as a bugtracker ;]

Comment: Quite right dude. I was hoping it was not a bug but yet another change they'd made. Generally speaking, I post a problem, get no response for awhile, and then slog through their insane bug tracking system with it's different accounts etc. They're changing things up at the moment so hopefully things are getting better.